# Changing return value of fundamental type and class type

Tags: c++

There is such code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int returnnumber() { return 2; }
std::string returntext() { return "siema"; }

int main() {

    std::cout << (returntext() += "cze") << std::endl; // siemacze
    //std::cout << (returnnumber() += 2) << std::endl; error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

    return 0;
}
```

Why is it possible to change return value of std::string, but not int?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `std::string` is a class type with a defined `+=` operator as a member function.

And the standard allows you to call member functions on rvalues.

A silly consequence of that is that:

```
struct S { int x; };
S foo() { return S(); }

int main()
{
    foo() = S();    // OK, uses member assignment operator.
    foo().x = 666;  // !Nah, can't assign to rvalue of built-in type.
}
```

compilation results:

> ```
> Comeau C/C++ 4.3.10.1 (Oct  6 2008 11:28:09) for ONLINE_EVALUATION_BETA2
> Copyright 1988-2008 Comeau Computing.  All rights reserved.
> MODE:strict errors C++ C++0x_extensions
> "ComeauTest.c", line 7: error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
> foo().x = 666;  // !Nah, can't assign to rvalue of built-in type.
> ^
> 1 error detected in the compilation of "ComeauTest.c".
> ```

However, compilers differ (or used to differ) about how strictly they applied this subtle rule, or if at all.

Comment: Well, but for `int` the operator `+=` is defined as well.

Comment: @Vlad: for `int` the `+=` is the *built-in* `operator=`, while for `std::string` it's a member function. I'm updating my answer to make that more clear. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I wonder why there is a difference: if member operators are allowed to be applied to rvalues, why is the same not allowed for built-in operators?

Comment: @Vlad: I don't know, but regarding a very similar question Bjarne Stroustrup (the language designer) replied that it was mostly an historical accident. He had meant to sit down and address the issue, but found he didn't have time. There's much that is like that... Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

The left hand side of an assignment operator for a built-in type must be a modifiable *lvalue* but the return value of a function is always an *rvalue* if the function doesn't return a reference type.

`operator+=` is a member function of `std::string` and you can call a member function on an *rvalue* of class type.

Comment: Did you mean "left hand side of an assignment operator?"

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason

```
std::string("siema") += "cze";
```

works.

You are constructing a new object and applying the `operator +=` (which `std::string` has) to it.

Trying this with it won't work as your function returns an `rvalue`. It would be like:

```
2 += 2
```

You can toy around with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int& returnnumber() { int * k = new int; *k = 2; return *k; }
std::string returntext() { return "siema"; }

int main() {

    std::cout << (returntext() += "cze") << std::endl; // siemacze
    std::cout << (returnnumber() += 2) << std::endl; //no error
    std::string("siema") += "cze";
    return 0;
}
```

But this will lead to a memory leak, so don't do it. It's just a proof of concept that returning an `lvalue` would work.

Comment: Hi Luchian :) Doesn't `returntext` return an rvalue as well?

Comment: Charles Bailey has written: but the return value of a function is always an rvalue if the function doesn't return a reference type. Then returntext returns rvalue or lvalue?

Comment: `returntext` does indeed return an rvalue of type `std::string` (3.10/5 in C++03). The built-in assignments require an lvalue (this rule inherited from C, I suppose, although in theory C++ could have changed if it if wanted to). However member functions, including operators overloaded as members, can be called on rvalues. Since `int` doesn't have any member functions whereas `string` does, those two rules result in an inconsistency. In C++11 there are loads more types of *value, I still haven't got it all straight so I won't try to refer to it, but the effect is the same.

Comment: On a second look, my clarification was a little lazy. It's more precise to say that `returntext` returns a `std::string` (and in general functions return either objects or references), and that the the expression `returntext()` is an rvalue (which in this case refers to the object returned by the function call). That's because to be precise, objects are not lvalues or rvalues, l-or-r-ness is a property of expressions.

Answer (score 0):

`returntext()` returns a `std::string` which can be modified in later stages say with `+=operator`.  However, although `returnnumber()` returns an `int`, the function itself is returning `2` which is by defualt a `const int` and is not changeable and that's why compiler complains.